Keyed dependency injection: obtaining an object and its key
I am currently using keyed dependency injection to create my ASP.NET server.
I have a set of objects I am registering:
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IFoo, Foo>("Foo")
builder.Services.AddKeyedSingleton<IFoo, Bar>("Bar")

And later on, I have another object, IFooController, that performs actions on each IFoo. The object IFooController is instantiated with every IFoo and its key as an id, that is currently registered using
builder.Services.AddScoped<IFooController>((provider) => 
{
        List<(string, IFoo)> ifoos = [
                ("Foo", provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<IFoo>("Foo")),
                ("Bar", provider.GetRequiredKeyedService<IFoo>("Bar"))
        ]

        return ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<FooBarController>(provider, ifoos)
}

This is done this way since the number of IFoo objects in the future will change with different builds.
Is there a way to iterate through all of the registered IFoo objects and also retrieve their key so in the future, I will only have to register the IFoo in one place?
An alternative option is to add the string id in to IFoo but would like to explore other options first.

You can request all IFoo by adding IEnumerable<IFoo> as a depedency instead of just IFoo. Keys are used to request a specific instance, not act as dictionaries.
